# Opening Sub Tab On Clicking Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have the following code to display tabbed content.

At the moment clicking '#tabs1' shows the sub links, but the user has to click '#sub1' for the content to display.

When '#tabs1' is clicked, I'd like the first subtab ('#sub1') of that section to be displayed automatically. Any ideas how I would achieve this?

```
<nav class="inner-nav top">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#tabs1">Tabs One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs2">Tabs Two</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Tabs #1 Begin -->

    <section class="tab-content" id="tabs1">

        <nav class="inner-nav sub">
            <ul>

                <li><a href="#1sub1">Sub Tab1 One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#1sub2">Sub Tab1 Two</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section class="tab-content" id="1sub1">

            // Sub Tab One Content

        </section>

        <section class="tab-content" id="1sub2">

            // Sub Tab Two Content

        </section>

    </section>

    <!-- Tabs #1 End -->


    <!-- Tabs #2 Begin -->

    <section class="tab-content" id="tabs2">

        <nav class="inner-nav sub">
            <ul>

                <li><a href="#2sub1">Sub Tab2 One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2sub2">Sub Tab2 Two</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section class="tab-content" id="2sub1">

            // Sub Tab2 One Content

        </section>

        <section class="tab-content" id="2sub2">

            // Sub Tab2 Two Content

        </section>

    </section>

    <!-- Tabs #2 End -->
```

////  jQuery:

```
<script>

        jQuery(function () {
        jQuery(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
        jQuery(".inner-nav li:first").addClass("active");

        jQuery(".inner-nav a").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
        });

        var hash = jQuery.trim( window.location.hash );

        if (hash) jQuery('.inner-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

        if (location.hash) {
  setTimeout(function() {

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 1);
}

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I can't see tabs1 click function you're trying with....

Comment: We can understand more easily if you can post a sample fiddle of your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bogcudto/1/ Hope that helps explain  things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/bogcudto/2/)

i have added two lines of code to the existing code

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
    $(".inner-nav li:first").addClass("active");

    $(".inner-nav a").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).find('a').eq(0).trigger('click'); // This is a new line
    })
    .eq(0).trigger('click'); // This is a new line

    var hash = $.trim(window.location.hash);

    if (hash) $('.inner-nav a[href$="' + hash + '"]').trigger('click');

    if (location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }, 1);
    }

});
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks Cerlin Boss! Exactly what I was trying to achieve.